# Calculating the residue of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $f(z) = \frac{1+z}{1-\cos(z)}$  I wish to calculate the residue of $f$ at $0$, $2\pi$ and $-2\pi$.

I believe this can be done by the following since $f$ has simple poles at these points

$Res(f, 0) = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} { zf(z)} = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} { \frac{z+z^2}{1-\cos(z)}} = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} { \frac{1+2z}{\sin(z)}}=1$

Edit: I realize this last equality is wrong, it should be infinity, which leads me to believe that my method is bad

In a similar way I have calculated $Res(f, 2\pi) = 1 +2\pi$ and $Res(f, -2\pi) = 1 - 2\pi$

Edit: also wrong, same mistake

Thanks in advance

Comment: You function is meromorphic: it has no need for branch cuts.

Comment: @Elliot The last limit you wrote in line 3 is $\infty.$

Comment: Okay, well that was a dumb mistake. So infinity probably means I am doing something wrong, unless a residue of infinity is meaningful somehow

Comment: As a matter of fact, all your points give **double** poles since $1-\cos(z)=2\sin^2\frac{z}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

At $0:$ $1-\cos z = z^2/2! -z^4/4!+ \cdots = (z^2/2)(1+ g(z)).$ So we are looking at

$$f(z) = 2(1+z)\cdot \frac{1}{z^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+g(z)}$$

near $0.$ The last factor is analytic near $0,$ equals $1$ at $0$ and is an even function of $z.$ The last factor therfore looks like $1 +az^2 + \cdots$ near $0.$ So the Laurent expansion of $f$ about $0$ is

$$\frac{2}{z^2}+ \frac{2}{z}+ \cdots$$

Hence $\text {Res}(f,0) = 2.$

Comment: I follow you up to the Laurent series, how do you get that from your expression for f(z) and g(z)?

Comment: We have

$$(\frac{2}{z^2}+ \frac{2}{z})(1 +az^2 + \cdots)=

\frac{2}{z^2}+ \frac{2}{z} +2a + 2az + \cdots$$